# Create a function with a column name as an argument (with grouping)

Tags: r, statistics

I want to write a function that takes a data frame, grouping a variable(a column) and a variable (also a column).
From reading multiple stakcflow attempts at cracking this, mostly recommended using arguments as strings.

My initial code to check for normality using the Shapiro-Wilk test for multiple data frames and variables was unsuccessful.

```
check_normality <- function(d, x_grouping_variable, y_cont_var){
   d %>%
      group_by([[x_grouping_variable]]) %>%
      summarise(`W Statistic` = shapiro.test([[y_cont_var]])$statistic,
                `p-value` = shapiro.test([[y_cont_var]])$p.value)

   return(shapiro.test([[y_cont_var]])$p.value)
}
```

ERROR:

```
Error: unexpected '[[' in "  return(shapiro.test([["
```

My attempt to fix it using this code was also unsuccessful.

```
check_normality <- function(d, x_grouping_variable, y_cont_var){
  d %>%
    group_by(((!! sym(x_grouping_variable)))) %>%
    summarise(`W Statistic` = shapiro.test((!! sym(y_cont_var)))$statistic,
          `p-value` = shapiro.test((!! sym(y_cont_var)))$p.value)

  return(shapiro.test((!! sym(y_cont_var)))$p.value)
}

check_normality(df, "RHF", "duratoin_days")
```

the error :

```
Error in !sym(y_cont_var) : invalid argument type
3.stopifnot(is.numeric(x))
2.shapiro.test((!!sym(y_cont_var)))
1.check_normality(df, "RHF", "duratoin_days")
```

Comment: In the function you didn't assign the output.  The `return` statement is not clear.  You don't need that line

Comment: i.e. if you remove the `return` statement, it works `> check_normality(iris, "Species", "Sepal.Length")
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  `(Species)` `W Statistic` `p-value`
  <fct>               <dbl>     <dbl>
1 setosa              0.978     0.460
2 versicolor          0.978     0.465
3 virginica           0.971     0.258`

Comment: Thank you, sir. It worked out fine! appreciate it!